# how to know upgraded packages

Tags: 14.04, apt

How would I come to know, what all packages has been upgraded?

Today I upgraded some of the packages, but I have forgotten those, I would like know what are those packages.

Please help me to find it.

Comment: Have a look at `/var/log/apt/history.log`.

Answer (score 1):

All the operations performed by Apt are recorded in `/var/log/apt/history.log`. In the case of package upgrades, the recorded information includes the date and time the upgrade was made, the name of the user who performed it, the actual command line run, and the name of upgraded packages together with the version numbers before and after the upgrade. A example entry looks like this:

```
Start-Date: 2016-04-26  15:32:49
Commandline: apt-get upgrade
Requested-By: firas (1000)
Upgrade: language-selector-common:amd64 (0.165, 0.165.1), python3-distupgrade:amd64 (1:16.04.13, 1:16.04.14), ubuntu-release-upgrader-core:amd64 (1:16.04.13, 1:16.04.14)
End-Date: 2016-04-26  15:33:01
```

In addition, the actual terminal output is recorded in `/var/log/apt/term.log`.